# Renaming a label in jira on demand via the application

Tags: label, jira

I have created an issue in Jira (Attlassian on Demand) and added a label. Labels after creating them (in my instance) can then be reused again in the future.

I have 2 similar labels and want to rename one of the labels.

How do I do this using the Jira on Demand application (and not via a back-end SQL update).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do so using the [On Demand application](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-26128). To do so, you can use the [Label Bot add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ca.uwo.jira.plugins.labelbot):

> [Label Bot](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ca.uwo.jira.plugins.labelbot) makes maintaining labels on Jira issues easy by automatically replacing, merging and removing labels based on a set of easily configurable rules. Performs actions on all labels found in your Jira instance:
>
> > 1. Ignores labels matching pattern matching.
> > 2. Drops all labels from uppercase to lowercase.
> > 3. Replaces one label with another.
> > 4. Merges two or more labels into a single label.
> > 5. Removes unwanted labels.